# Tomcat Restart Error - BalancerFilter

Tags: tomcat, ssl, catalina

I am trying to setup an SSL for Tomcat and when I restart the service I get the following issues in the log:

> ... org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>
> SEVERE: Exception starting filter BalancerFilter
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester ...

This was working fine before the restart. Only localhost:8080 works but https://localhost:8443 doesn't. As far as I can tell this **isn't** an issue with the settings in tomcat/conf/server.xml.

Some leads have pointed me in the direction of downloading this digest plugin, but that doesn't make sense if this worked previous to the startup.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace - does it include a `ClassNotFound` exception

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a misconfiguration in the Tomcat/conf/server.xml file causing the secure port to malfunction.

The SSL has been setup and starts correctly, yet still displays the bit about the Digest in the logs. I am not entirely sure as to what it pertains, but it seems to have no effect on the Tomcat instance, which now runs fine.